# Datetimepicker specific disable date, how to set variables

Tags: jquery, date, time, datetimepicker

I  have a code of my `datetimepicker` which will disable specific hours by date.

```
var specificDates = ['2016/01/11','2016/01/10']; 
var hoursToTakeAway = [[14,15],[17]]; 
var lastDate; 
$('#datetimepicker_dark').datetimepicker({
        format:'Y/m/d H:i',
        timepicker: true, theme:'dark',
        onGenerate:function(ct,$i){
          $('.xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time').prop('disabled',false).fadeTo("fast",1).removeClass('disabled');
          //$('.xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time').prop('disabled',false);
          var ind = specificDates.indexOf(ct.dateFormat('Y/m/d'));
          if(ind !== -1) {
              $('.xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time').each(function(index){
                  if(hoursToTakeAway[ind].indexOf(parseInt($(this).text())) !== -1){
                      $(this).addClass('disabled');
                      $(this).fadeTo("fast",.3);
                      $(this).prop('disabled',true);
                  }
              });
          }
        }   
    });
```

It works well, but I want to know how to set `specificDates` and `hoursToTakeAway` by dates saved in my database as string.

I am using this format `Y/m/d H:i` like that:

[image]

PD: I tried creating a character string and explode it with php creating arrays like that:

array_date
(
    [0] => 2015/12/28
    [1] => 2015/12/28
    [2] => 2015/12/01)

array_hour
(
    [0] => 18:00
    [1] => 19:00
    [2] => 15:00)

array_hour2
(
    [0] => 18
    [1] => 19
    [2] => 15)

But I still without a solution to set my variables the way I want.